# Is any simple way that I can simplify the multiple sqls into one

Tags: hive, hiveql

Sorry for I can't use one sentence to describe my question in title.
I've got a table that looks like this:

```
item_id,
attr_1,
attr_2,
attr_3,
...,
attr_n,
date
```

What I'd like to achieve looks like that:

```
select
   attr_1, 
   avg(attr_2) i_want_1
from 
   table
where date between some_range
group by attr_1

select
   attr_1,
   attr_2, 
   avg(attr_3) i_want_2
from 
   table
where date between some_range
group by attr_1, attr_2

select
   attr_5,
   attr_6, 
   avg(attr_7) i_want_3
from 
   table
where date between some_range
group by attr_5, attr_6
```

PS: an item_id can appear in many dates.
Then I need to left join with every multiple attrs to get the final table I want, looks like that:

```
item_id,
i_want_1,
i_want_2,
i_want_3,
....
```

If I only do the things above in a single date, it can easily achieve with `over` function like this:

```
select 
    item_id, 
    avg(attr_2) over(partition by attr_1) i_want_1,
    avg(attr_3) over(partition by attr_1, attr_2) i_want_2,
    avg(attr_7) over(partition by attr_5, attr_6) i_want_3
from 
    table
where date = single_date
```

Is there any way to use function like `over` to achieve the final result 
in one sql?
Or is there any simple way to solve problem like this?
I have too many i_wants, and if I did the above, then the sql file is out of control.
I will be appreciated if anyone can help or give some advice, because I've got a headache now due to the increasing sqls.

Comment: I've never used hive - but most dialects of SQL have a WITH clause for that kind of thing.

Comment: What is wrong with using `where date between + avg() over() `?

Comment: is the date filter different for all avg() queries? The problem is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You should read about and convert your current SQL representation to the `WITH` clause in Apache Hive. Here's the page from ASF - [Common Table Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression)

Using a CTE makes a lot of sense here since you need to work on the same base table and the last operation itself involves a JOIN.

You can also run the desired `OVER` clause with the required partition function to emulate any behavior fit for your needs and analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below -

```
select distinct
    item_id, 
    avg(case when date between somerange then null else attr_2 end) over(partition by attr_1) i_want_1,
    avg(case when date between somerange then null else attr_3 end) over(partition by attr_1, attr_2) i_want_2,
    avg(case when date between somerange then null else attr_7 end) over(partition by attr_5, attr_6) i_want_3
from 
    table;
```

Since you need average, based on filter for each avg function null values will be ignored.

Comment: The `item_id` of final result should be unique. Currently, I can get a max(attr) with group by `item_id`, but it looks so ugly.

Comment: Result will be same for each item-id,  why dint you try distinct